# Tengo un problema con css

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero poner ese button donde puse el dibujo y no se porqué pero no me deja intente probar con display:block;
aqui les dejo mi codigo

```css
#btn1 {
  width: 40%;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<secion class="nft_1">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4N2ONP4lunTaR-F3Gi8HAi5vjxTHNSAM4lw0EjcJbcOJzeH2fOEfyK-Aj1yDXSJguXiGIE7BHR94pAVlE3bvTasuUDB79RMOwhcn=w600" width="100px" height="100px" alt="">
</secion>
<button type="button" id="" class="btn btn-dark">Play with that NFT!</button>

<section class="nft_2">
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/itqm9xm_xIMaJkVqeyeNI885XHP1OSjqf2a7JdgUo-V3GScKhWDahI5X4Yj1LM49-5IYlBZOMjcljQQSKbTci1SY2G644xtawdLl5g=w600" width="100px" height="100px">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Play with that NFT!</button>
</section>
```

pd: soy principiante en programación :P

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como quedarían los botones de bajo de las imágenes. No se porque te sale la imagen tan hacia la derecha yo lo he probado y me salen una de bajo de otra.

```css
img{
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:1rem;
  margin-top:1rem;
}
#btn1 { 
    margin-top:1rem;
    margin-bottom:1rem;
    width: 40%;
    display: block;
    margin-right:6px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<secion class="nft_1"> 
  <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4N2ONP4lunTaR-F3Gi8HAi5vjxTHNSAM4lw0EjcJbcOJzeH2fOEfyK-Aj1yDXSJguXiGIE7BHR94pAVlE3bvTasuUDB79RMOwhcn=w600" width="100px" height="100px" alt=""> 
  <button type="button"  id="" class="btn btn-dark">Play with that NFT!</button> 
</secion> 
  

<section class="nft_2"> 
   <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/itqm9xm_xIMaJkVqeyeNI885XHP1OSjqf2a7JdgUo-V3GScKhWDahI5X4Yj1LM49-5IYlBZOMjcljQQSKbTci1SY2G644xtawdLl5g=w600" width="100px" height="100px"> 
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Play with that NFT!</button> 
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: esta fantastico! pero cuando lo quiero mover la imagen un poco mas hacia la derecha con un margin-left: 20%; se mueve la imagen pero no el button

Comment: Genera un contenedor dentro del section para la imágen y el botón, luego podrás aplicar el margin a ese contenedor y ya se deplazarán en bloque todos los elementos hijo.